# Get reified type parameter kclass of reified generic type

Tags: kotlin, generics, reflection

Given a reified type parameter `T`, if that type is a `List`, how can I get the list's item type?

I tried overloading the reified method with `T : Any` and `T : List` and also `TItem : Any, TList: List<TItem>` but that doesn't compile due to conflicting overloads.

***Fails to compile, conflicting overloads***

```
inline fun <reified T> getRequiredVariable(variableName: String) =
  // ... implementation

inline fun <reified TItem, reified TList : List> getRequiredVariable(variableName: String) =
  // ... implementation
```

***Failed workaround attempt***

```kotlin
inline fun <reified T : Any> getRequiredVariable(variableName: String) =
    if (T::class.isSubclassOf(List::class)) {
        val tKClass = T::class
        val itemType = tKClass.typeParameters[0] // Won't work, even though T is reified, the type parameter apparently is not
        val itemClassifier = itemType.createType().classifier
        val itemKClass = itemClassifier as KClass<*> // Fails, KTypeParamaterImpl is not KClass<*>
        getRequiredListVariable(variableName, itemKClass) as? T
    } else {
        getRequiredVariable(variableName, T::class)
    }
```

Comment: What is your use case for this, by the way? Maybe I could refine my answer or hint at another direction depending on the bigger picture.

Comment: @Joffrey thank you for the good inquiry; I always tell my devs to go back to the original problem too and yet I failed to do it myself. The class is a generic network call mock and has `Map<String, String>` for the variables where the value is JSON. I want to deserialize to the right type, which works fine for simple values but requires different code for lists (and maps, but I haven't got there yet).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is that you want to access type *arguments* but the `KClass`/`Class` abstraction only gives access to type *parameters* (the things declared in the class itself, not the actual types passed in this specific reified call site).

You shouldn't use the class for this, but the `Type`/`KType` instead. There is a convenient [typeOf](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.reflect/type-of.html) function to access it on a reified type, and then you can access the type arguments via the [arguments](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.reflect/-k-type/arguments.html) property:

```kotlin
val typeArgs = typeOf<T>().arguments
```

Once you have those, you can access their type and the classifier of that type like you did in your existing code, but this time it will be those of the actual type arguments.

```kotlin
inline fun <reified T : Any> getRequiredVariable(variableName: String) =
    if (T::class.isSubclassOf(List::class)) {
        val itemTypeProjection = typeOf<T>().arguments[0]
        val itemType = itemTypeProjection.type ?: error("Cannot get list item type from List<*>")
        val itemKClass = itemType.classifier as? KClass<*> ?: error("The list item type is not denotable in Kotlin")
        getRequiredListVariable(variableName, itemKClass) as? T
    } else {
        getRequiredVariable(variableName, T::class)
    }
```

Note, however, that accessing the type argument 0 will not generally give you the item type for any implementation class of `List`. For instance, if the type is `class MyStringList : List<String>`, it has no type argument and yet it's a subtype of `List`. Even worse, it could have a type argument that has nothing to do with the list elements, as in `class MyWeirdClass<X> : List<String>` (using X for something unrelated). To overcome this, you might need to go up the hierarchy of supertypes in order to find the type of the `List` interface used in the declaration of `T`'s type - and this will likely be a pain.

Comment: Perfect, thank you. I'm late in seeing this but hopefully can use it to refactor. I thought `KType` might have something to do with it but had trouble going back and forth between that and `KClass`. Your answer looks like exactly what I needed!